# Access to fetch from origin localhost blocked by CORS policy, post using ajax does not. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch-api

This is not problem about CORS, so don't suggest workarounds with browser plugins or changes to server code. I just want to understand why ajax post works, and fetch post doesn't!

Currently using jQuery and ajax for doing some getting and posting. Making a post request from localhost with ajax work fine without any problems with a request similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.example.com/endpoint',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        moment: {
            parameters: 'some params',
            url: 'https://example.com',
            caption: 'caption'
        }
    }
})
```

I have decided to start using fetch instead of ajax, but doing what "looks" like the same request with fetch from the same localhost conditions fails with the error message

> Access to fetch at 'http://api.example.com/endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

The fetch request looks similar to this:

```
fetch('https://api.example.com/endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    cache: 'no-cache',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        moment: {
            parameters: 'some params',
            url: 'https://example.com',
            caption: 'caption'
        }
    })
})
```

I just want to understand what jQuery does to get around this? I have been looking at the source on github and don't see anything special. Or is it limitations added to the fetch api which XMLHttpRequest doesn't have?

EDIT:

In the network tab the ajax request looks like this:

```
General
    Request URL: https://api.example.com/endpoint
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Remote Address: ip:80
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Headers
    Accept: */*
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    DNT: 1
    Referer: http://localhost/index.html?target=...
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
```

While the fetch request looks like:

```
General
    Request URL: https://api.example.com/endpoint
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Headers
    Content-Type: application/json
    DNT: 1
    Referer: http://localhost/index.html?target=...
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
```

Adding all those headers from ajax to the fetch request made no difference.

Comment: jQuery does nothing special to get around CORS, as it's not technically possible. Are you 100% sure the jQuery request hasn't been cached? In theory neither of these requests should work if CORS restrictions are in place.

Comment: What do the both request look like in the Network tab? Are there any differences in, for example, headers?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I'm sure.  I have cleared all the cache in my browser multiple times between testing the different requests.

Comment: @mbojko thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my question with the content from both requests.

Comment: They look like the response headers, do you have the request headers?

Comment: I see at least two differences: `Accept: */*` in jQuery (absent in fetch), and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in jQuery vs fetch's `application/json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being threefold.

1. Which Rory commented, jQuery doesn't change anything to CORS. This was my error, I had two end points, one for development which accepts cross domain calls and one which doesn't, they looked very similar and behaves the same, with the exception of CORS.
2. jQuery by default set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` if none is provided. Fetch doesn't default to anything specific.
3. jQuery also parses the data sent automatically to a format which is accepted by php and ruby backends. Which looks something like

this:

```
moment[parameters]: value
moment[url]: value
moment[caption]: value
```

So I had to write my own version of jQuery's $.param() function as I haven't found anything in Javascript which can encode child objects as well.